# Adding javascript blocks to a single file and adding it to the header

Tags: javascript

I don't know how to do it, but I have a few js code blocks in my sites header like the StatCounter tracking code, facebook like button js code, etc.

Now the thing is that I want to combine all the external js code blocks into one file so that I can add it either in the header or footer section. Can any one guide me on how can I add these code blocks into a single file?

Answer (score 0):

Just chuck them in a file, say `your-theme/js/global.js` and enqueue it in `functions.php`:

```
function wpse_180397_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'wpse-180397-global', /* Unique ID */
        get_bloginfo( 'template_url' ) . '/js/global.js', /* URL */
        array(), /* Dependencies */
        true /* In footer */
    );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_180397_scripts' );
```

Answer (score 0):

1. create a new javascript (.js) file with any text editor you'd choose.
2. start it with `jQuery(document).ready(function() {`
3. copy and paste all other code blocks you've got, with out the `<script>` start and end tags.
4. if you have `jQuery(document).ready(function() {` in the beginning of one of these code blocks you should consider removing, but it carefully. don't forget to remove also the `}` end tag;
5. if you followed step 2, your javascript file should end up with `}`.
6. close the file and save it with any name you'd choose. lets say `global.js`.
7. finally add the function to `functions.php` file as TheDeadMedic suggested.